# PHP APC is installed but not getting hit?

Tags: php, caching, apc

I'm not familiar with PHP APC but i've installed on the RHEL Server and installation was finished without any problem. Then i supposed it should be working fine by checking `PHP Info` and there is showing `APC` Module loaded.

But when i call the `apc.php` which is like a Dashboard of APC, there is showing some of:

```
..
Cached Files: 0 ( 0.0 Bytes)
Hits: 1
..
Cache full count: 0
..
```

and all `Cache Entries` are blank
.. after 3 weeks.

No special error or warning is given also.

So i'm sure it is not working (or) caching is not happening actually.

- Any suggestion (or) is there something i need to fix, to make it work?

Comment: Your code? What have you done? what have you tried?

Comment: error code, anything? tried setting display_errors to 1 ?

Comment: Please paste the APC section of phpinfo here.